# Cannot deploy Node js app to Azure ("do not have permission")

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I have a Wordle-esque app that I want to deploy using Azure. Repo [here](https://github.com/andrewblance/shetland-wordle). It is a fork from a popular open-source project, and I can also locally build and run the game. Locally, it runs perfectly.

I am trying to use Azure App Services to deploy it, using a Github Action. All the Actions pass, and the App can be successfully built. However, when I try to view the deployment [here](https://shetland-wordle.azurewebsites.net/) the only error I am receiving is

`You do not have permission to view this directory or page.`

Since it runs locally, and it pass its github action build, I do not know how to proceed here. I have tried restarting the app, and changing the resources I am using to host it, but that does not work. Some other answers seem to suggest the problem is about it not finding `index.html`, but I can access that through https://shetland-wordle.azurewebsites.net/public/index.html and the page is blank.

If i look under wwwroot/ in the Azure debugger I see the following file structure:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out it was something strange with `package.json`. I needed to change the path to my react scripts:

`"start": "node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start"`

Not sure if its good practise to do this, but it works now